g++ print source-mapped file path in error
I have a C++ file that I'm compiling with g++ with the -ffile-prefix-map option. Is there a way to tell g++ to print the remapped file name when there are build errors? That way, clickable file names in my terminal would point to the correct source files.
For example, these commands:
mkdir cpp_test
echo 'invalid' > cpp_test/a.cpp
g++ -ffile-prefix-map=cpp-test/a.cpp=hello.cpp -g cpp-test/a.cpp -o cpp-test/a.out

print the error:
cpp-test/a.cpp:1:1: error: ‘invalid’ does not name a type
    1 | invalid
      | ^~~~~~~

while I want it to print:
hello.cpp:1:1: error: ‘invalid’ does not name a type
    1 | invalid
      | ^~~~~~~

Is that possible?

Perhaps the #line directive? Assuming that you auto-generate the source file you're building.

Unfortunately, the files are written by hand. My build process involves copying source files to one of multiple directories before building. Some files go to dir A, some to dir B, and some go to both.

If you're on a Linux or macOS system (or other POSIX or Unix-like system) then you could use the aptly named cat command to concatenate a line with the #line directive, followed by the actual file, instead of just copying. Perhaps something like cat \echo "#line 1 "$ACTUAL_FILE""` $ACTUAL_FILE > $NEW_FILE` (not tested)

Yeah, that workaround should work. I was hoping that GCC had some option to do this built-in.
